# GitLab: Give someone only access to the Container Registry?

Tags: gitlab

I want to give a frontend developer rights **only to pull/read from the GitLab container registry**. In order to test some things in the frontend he needs also the backend container.

But **I dont want to give access to the full gitlab project**, so that he can clone the whole repo. I only want to give him access to pull the container from the registry (because how I understand it, he wont have the possibility to access the code then).

Is this even possible with GitLab? Seems like Container Registry access needs whole project access?
If this is not possible with GitLab it should somehow be possible with AWS Registry instead or? (Any suggestions for this usecase I would be very thankfull for.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While GitLab's user permission scheme lacks some granularity, you might be able to workaround this limitation.

One would be to make the project publicly/internally accessible through its visibility settings. Users only need read ability in order to access the container registry. Obviously, this may not be acceptable if your images are intended to be more private/secret.

One other possible mechanism for granting access to container registry might be to create a [project access token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/settings/project_access_tokens.html) with just `read_registry` scope and distribute that token to your users that need to read the image registry for the project.

The same could be done with [group access tokens](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/settings/group_access_tokens.html), too. This may be useful to reduce management overhead if you have many projects with this need.